# How to calculate (or rotate) four points in a plane perpendicular to a line

Tags: math, 3d, rotation, godot

I need to generate a 4 point square "cap" to a 3D line segment that is perpendicular to said 3D line. Theoretically the line can be any line in 3D space and is described by 2 points in 3D space.

[image]

So far I have been able to correctly rotate the points around the Y axis (which in Godot points up) by changing their X and Z positions by using a 2D rotation algorithm but I see no way of incorporating the 3rd dimension rotation.

As far as I understand it takes an entirely new algorithm to rotate points in 3D space (Quaternions?) but I have not found code applications of this that I can understand.

A way to think about it is that I need to generate a square plane from its normal. The points have to form a square of side "L" so I can't use algorithms that generate random points.

I Thank you for any assistance you can provide.

Comment: Can you include a screen shot or a sketch of what you are trying to do? Link to imgur.com and someone with higher rep can embed it to the question.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/NgffJvp

I need to generate the 4 points which are coplanar and describe a square with each side measuring L on the plane which is perpendicular to the line.

Comment: The plane wound also be pass through one of the points which describe the line.

Comment: Thanks for embedding the image!

Comment: Just so you are clear. Quaternions encode rotations in terms of an arbitrary axis and an angle. That's it. There is nothing you can do with quaternions that you can't do with rotation matrices. You do need to familiarize yourself with the [Rodrigues rotation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues%27_rotation_formula) which builds rotation matrices from axis-angle. In your case the line is a rotation axis, and you rotate four times by 90° to get your four points.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that without a rotation matrix, just by vector calculus.

A point `S` along the line through `P` and `Q` is computed by `P + t.PQ` where `t` is a scalar. Now take any point in space, let `R` and find its orthogonal projection `S` on the line, by solving `RS.PQ = 0` or `(RP + t.PQ).PQ = 0`, or `t = - RP.PQ / PQ.PQ`.

The vector `RS` defines the direction of a diagonal of the square. Hence we find a first vertex `R'` at length `L/√2` along `SR` by applying a coefficient `L/√2|SR|`.

A second vertex `U` is such that `U = S + R'S`.

The remaining two vertices `V` and `W` are found by constructing the vector `VS` orthogonal to `RS` using a cross product with the direction of the line, `R'S x PQ/|PQ|`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answering! I solved it with JohanC's Algorithm I will try this next time.

Comment: Nice sketch! You are either a master of powerpoint, or used some other software. Please tell.

Comment: @ja72: MS Word.

Answer (score 1):

Quaternions are interesting, but not necessary. A rotation matrix can be used here.

Outline of the algorithm:

- suppose p1 and p2 are the 3D points of the line
- let p1p2 be the normalized vector from p1 towards p2 (normalize(p2-p1))
- place four points s1, s2, s3, s4 at (0,1,1), (0,1,-1), (0,-1,-1), (0,-1,1); these are the initial positions of the points forming a square perpendicular to the x-axis; if too small, just multiply them by a desired size
- let xvec be a unit x-vector (1, 0, 0)
- let axis be the crossproduct of p1p2 and xvec
- if the norm of axis is zero, no rotation is needed --> skip the rotation steps, else:

  - theta = acos(dotproduct(xvec, p1p2))
  - build a rotation matrix as in [this wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Rotation_matrix_from_axis_and_angle) using theta and axis
  - multiply s1, s2, s3, s4 with the rotation matrix
- add p1 to s1, s2, s3, s4 to get the square at position p1
- add p2 to s1, s2, s3, s4 to get the square at position p2

PS: If you choose s1, s2, s3, s4 as (1,0,1), (1,0,-1), (-1,0,-1), (-1,0,1), you can do the same with yvec = (0,1,0)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will try to implement it and report back as soon as I can.

Comment: I updated the answer for when you would choose your initial position around the y-axis (instead of x). Also the sign of s4 was the same as s2, while it should be opposite.

Answer (score 1):

```
func drawline(starting_point, finishing_point):

var width = 0.1

var diference_vector = finishing_point - starting_point
var diference_vector_norm = sqrt(pow(diference_vector[0],2.0) + pow(diference_vector[1],2.0) + pow(diference_vector[2],2.0))
var normalized_difference_vector

if diference_vector_norm != 0:
    normalized_difference_vector = Vector3(diference_vector[0]/diference_vector_norm, diference_vector[1]/diference_vector_norm, diference_vector[2]/diference_vector_norm)
else:
    normalized_difference_vector = Vector3(0,0,0)

var s1 = Vector3(0, width, -width)
var s2 = Vector3(0, width, width)
var s3 = Vector3(0, -width, width)
var s4 = Vector3(0, -width, -width)

var x_vec = Vector3(1,0,0)
var axis_vector = normalized_difference_vector.cross(x_vec)
var axis_vector_norm = sqrt(pow(axis_vector[0],2.0) + pow(axis_vector[1],2.0) + pow(axis_vector[2],2.0))

if axis_vector_norm != 0:
    var normalized_axis_vector = Vector3(axis_vector[0]/axis_vector_norm, axis_vector[1]/axis_vector_norm, axis_vector[2]/axis_vector_norm)
    var theta = acos(x_vec.dot(normalized_difference_vector))

    var matrix_0_0 = cos(theta) + (pow(normalized_axis_vector[0],2.0) * (1-cos(theta)))
    var matrix_0_1 = (normalized_axis_vector[0] * normalized_axis_vector[1] * (1-cos(theta))) - (normalized_axis_vector[2] * sin(theta))
    var matrix_0_2 = (normalized_axis_vector[0] * normalized_axis_vector[2] * (1-cos(theta))) + (normalized_axis_vector[1] * sin(theta))

    var matrix_1_0 = (normalized_axis_vector[1] * normalized_axis_vector[0] * (1-cos(theta))) + (normalized_axis_vector[2] * sin(theta))
    var matrix_1_1 = cos(theta) + (pow(normalized_axis_vector[1],2.0) * (1-cos(theta)))
    var matrix_1_2 = (normalized_axis_vector[1] * normalized_axis_vector[2] * (1-cos(theta))) - (normalized_axis_vector[0] * sin(theta))

    var matrix_2_0 = (normalized_axis_vector[2] * normalized_axis_vector[0] * (1-cos(theta))) - (normalized_axis_vector[1] * sin(theta))
    var matrix_2_1 = (normalized_axis_vector[2] * normalized_axis_vector[1] * (1-cos(theta))) - (normalized_axis_vector[0] * sin(theta))
    var matrix_2_2 = cos(theta) + (pow(normalized_axis_vector[2],2.0) * (1-cos(theta)))

    var matrix = Transform(Vector3(matrix_0_0, matrix_0_1, matrix_0_2), Vector3(matrix_1_0, matrix_1_1, matrix_1_2), Vector3(matrix_2_0, matrix_2_1, matrix_2_2), Vector3(0,0,0))

    var a1 = matrix.basis.xform(s1) + starting_point
    var a2 = matrix.basis.xform(s2) + starting_point
    var a3 = matrix.basis.xform(s3) + starting_point
    var a4 = matrix.basis.xform(s4) + starting_point

    var b1 = matrix.basis.xform(s1) + finishing_point
    var b2 = matrix.basis.xform(s2) + finishing_point
    var b3 = matrix.basis.xform(s3) + finishing_point
    var b4 = matrix.basis.xform(s4) + finishing_point
```

Comment: This is the code I ended up using for Godot (inside a Immediate Geometry node) I used JohanC's Answer to build it. Thank you very much to those that answered. I hope this helps the next person.

Next you need to draw either lines or triangles using those points in order to see anything in the game.